# Use local button styles during forwarded X11 session over SSH

Tags: 10.10, xorg, ssh, remote-desktop

Is it at all possible to have a forwarded X11 session be styled with something other than the default X button styles? It doesn't even appear to use my server's actual styles seeing as both computers are running Ubuntu 10.10. However, the window on the left is from the local machine, and window on the right is forwarded via `ssh -X`.

Is there any way to change this behavior to mimic the native button style or change it at all? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Contrary to what I said in my deleted answer, this should just work. If you run a gnome application using `ssh -X`, it should automatically use the settings from your local settings daemon. Is there anything unusual about your setup?

Comment: As sepp2k points out, there are likely different configuration mechanisms at play here: (1) GNOME applications will use `gnome-settings-daemon` if it's running; (2) GTK applications will use the `~/.gtkrc-2.0` file on the machine they're running on; (3) similarly, Qt/Xaw/Xtoolkit apps have their own (and different!) way of configuring style.  What applications are you interested in?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[This has apparently been discussed on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/69174/x11-looks-ugly-while-opening-a-remote-window-from-ssh-can-i-use-gtk-themes) as well;
[Suppressingfire's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/69174/x11-looks-ugly-while-opening-a-remote-window-from-ssh-can-i-use-gtk-themes/69175#69175) looks to me like the correct one:

1. Install your favorite Ubuntu GTK theme on the remote host as well;
2. Create a `~/.gtkrc-2.0` on the remote host, and include the theme's own gtkrc from it; e.g., if you're running Ubuntu with the ClearLooks theme on the remote host, you can add use this line:

   ```
   include "/usr/share/themes/ClearlooksClassic/gtk-2.0/gtkrc";
   ```

**Update from comments**

The GUI way:

```
sudo apt install lxappearance gnome-themes-extras
lxappearance
```

With this method you also can change other properties like icons

Comment: Both answers look to me like they're correct, and I rather think ephemient's answer is the one the OP wants, as it allows him to use his local settings.

Comment: This one worked best for me. I figured rendering was handled by the remote host. Thanks!

Comment: I skipped step 2. and used the `lxappearance` app (`sudo apt-get install lxappearance`) to configure the desktop theme. Credit to http://askubuntu.com/a/100412/250556

Comment: This methods works also for Bash on Ubuntu on Windows