# How do I apply themes to gtk applications when I'm using Awesome WM?

Tags: themes, gtk, awesome

No matter what I use, e.g. gtk-ctheme, and the other apps availible in the repos, gtk applications running under Awesome WM stay ugly.

The same apps look fine when I use unity.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you try to start gnome-settings-daemon ?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/82095/fonts-in-menu-are-larger-than-they-should-be-under-awesome-wm

Comment: @user49503 unfortunately it not only work with theme, but also screws down keyboard layout.

Answer (score 22):

Try installing lxappearance

```
sudo apt-get install lxappearance
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 5):

You can edit the gtk config files, like described here
http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Customizing_GTK_Apps

lxappearance  works fine too, but if you can't get it done with gtk-ctheme then it probably doesn't work for you either

Comment: While this technically answers the question, the link alone [isn't sufficient for a good answer by itself](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259). Now, this answer is unhelpful at this point because the wiki you pointed to is now closed.

Comment: The link is dead :(